# Lightweight Signature Pad With jQuery And Canvas - Drawpad

Tags: php, jquery

There is a brand new drawing pad (pen tool) plugin from Jquery found in that link:

https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/signature-draw-pad.html.

As it is new I cannot see how to transform it into image to save it to database with php.
I cannot find any explanation on how to use this plugin for that purpose.

Anyone has information on how to do that ?

Thank you !!

Comment: what is wrong with my question, just want to save that drawing to database with php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little inspect/devtools shows that the doodle/image/drawing is stored in html canvas element.

You can get the content of html canvas element with `toDataURL()` function.

Here is MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

Example: `var base64Image = $("#target canvas").get(0).toDataURL();`

You can then post it (example: via ajax, via form post, etc) to your backend and store the base64 in database.

Here is example snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // set background
  var urlBackground = 'https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/400';
  var imageBackground = new Image();
  imageBackground.src = urlBackground;
  //imageBackground.crossorigin = "anonymous";
  imageBackground.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
  $("#target").drawpad();
  var contextCanvas = $("#target canvas").get(0).getContext('2d');
  imageBackground.onload = function(){
    contextCanvas.drawImage(imageBackground, 0, 0);
  }
  
  // post the base64 image to some endpoint
  $("#saveToDatabase").click(function() {
    var base64Image = $("#target canvas").get(0).toDataURL();
    console.log(base64Image);
    $("#outputBase64FormInput").val(base64Image);
    $("#outputBase64").html(base64Image);
  });
  
  // form submit
  $("#myform").submit(function() {
    var base64Image = $("#target canvas").get(0).toDataURL();
    console.log(base64Image);
    $("#outputBase64FormInput").val(base64Image);
    $("#outputBase64").html(base64Image);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cnbilgin.github.io/jquery-drawpad/jquery-drawpad.css" />
   <style>
      body {background-color:rgb(248, 255, 227)}
      #target {
         width:500px;
         height:400px;
      }
   </style>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cnbilgin.github.io/jquery-drawpad/jquery-drawpad.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <button id="saveToDatabase">Save Drawing</button>
   <div id="target" class="drawpad-dashed"></div>
   <div id="outputBase64"></div>
   <form id='myform' method="POST">
     value1 <input id='value1' name='myvalue1' />
     value2 <input id='value2' name='myvalue2' />
     <input type='hidden' id='outputBase64FormInput' name='mybase64image'>
     <input type='submit'>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit:

the OP asked to add image in canvas (and also posted the image to endpoint)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's exactly what I wanted. But I miss one last thing. The target div has a background image inside of it like: <div id="target" class="drawpad-dashed" style="background: url(vacular.jpg) no-repeat center center;"></div>. How can I save the background image as well ? with your codes only the drawing is converted into image. How to get the background image as well ?

Comment: is the background supplied by user or by your app? if it's supplied by user then you just need to also post it as ```<input type=file...```, but if it's supplied by your app then you can always display it when user request your page

Comment: the image is supplied by my app, it's exactly what I do I call this image background along with the drawing, the issue is when the user edit the canvas the last drawing is lost the new drawing is kept.

Comment: the canvas is inside a form that must be fill and edit.

Comment: If only I could show you the situation by another means than stackoverflow, so that you may understand clearer ?

Comment: go ahead, you can use jsfiddle (and add the link to your fiddle to this question)

Comment: @Diasline answer edited, basically you want to add another form data to be posted along, and add background right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231397/discussion-between-diasline-and-kristian).

Comment: I created a new post I wish you see it so that you win new votes from me, behold the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67200382/clear-canvas-drawpad-jquery