# Clear canvas drawpad jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I'm using the drawing pad (pen tool) plugin of Jquery to draw with different colors and having an image in the canvas as background. My purpose is to have a button to clear the drawing over the canvas. The way I try to do it remove the background image along with the drawing. How can I keep the background and remove the drawing on clicking the clear button ?

My fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ub3s9go7/

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    // set background
    var urlBackground = 'https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/400';
    var imageBackground = new Image();
    imageBackground.src = urlBackground;
    imageBackground.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');

    $("#target").drawpad();

    var contextCanvas = $("#target canvas").get(0).getContext('2d');

    imageBackground.onload = function(){
    contextCanvas.drawImage(imageBackground, 0, 0);
    }

    // Need to clear only the drawing not the background image
    $("#clearDrawing").click(function() {
     contextCanvas.clearRect(0, 0, 750, 423);
    });

    

    });
    </script>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cnbilgin.github.io/jquery-drawpad/jquery-drawpad.css" />
    <style>
    body {background-color:rgb(248, 255, 227)}
    #target {
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cnbilgin.github.io/jquery-drawpad/jquery-drawpad.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="clearDrawing">Clear Drawing</button>
    <div id="target" class="drawpad-dashed"></div>
    

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Not the best solution in the world, but> contextCanvas.drawImage(imageBackground, 0, 0); after contextCanvas.clearRect(0, 0, 750, 423); ?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lq9w6gva/

Comment: ok, I see, many thanks. Just answer it so that I vote your answer

Comment: Well, i would, but i found the bug - try to use white. Hope you will find some better solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is an improvisation on my previous answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/67155647/3706717

So we have new requirement: delete/clear previous drawings

There are some possible approach here:

- @sinisake in comment suggested to reload the background so that we have fresh canvas with only the background intact (but for some reason, white doodle make the background gone)
- the library must have "delete" or "erase" doodle feature (which it didn't have)
- save each changes of the drawing when user click "save", so that user can "undo" to previous version of the drawing (like git's `git commit` and `git reset` command),  I'll be using this approach in my answer

Ideally, you should use server-side language and persistent storage (e.g.: database) to store user's doodling history. But in this case, to simulate such thing I'll be using javascript's localStorage API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

So every time I'm calling localStorage API, just assume that I'm calling some ajax to some endpoint.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0da572jy/3/

Here is stack fiddle (modified because browser didn't allow stack fiddle to use localStorage)

```js
// polyfill for localStorage API
var localStorage1 = {
  items: {},
  removeItem: function(key) {
    window.localStorage1.items[key] = null;
  },
  getItem: function(key) {
    return window.localStorage1.items[key];
  },
  setItem: function(key, val) {
    return window.localStorage1.items[key] = val;
  },
}
//window.localStorage = localStorage1;
window.localStorage1 = localStorage1;



$(document).ready(function() {
  
  
  $("#save").click(function() {
  
    // I already explained the #save logic in https://stackoverflow.com/a/67155647/3706717
    //console.log("save");
    var base64Image = $("#target canvas").get(0).toDataURL();
    //console.log(base64Image);
    $("#outputBase64FormInput").val(base64Image);
    $("#outputBase64").html(base64Image);
    
    // load/read saved states/histories
    var savedImageJson = window.localStorage1.getItem("savedImage");
    //console.log(savedImageJson);
    
    // if the history is undefined, create empty array
    if(savedImageJson == null || typeof savedImageJson == "undefined") savedImageJson = "[]";
    
    // parse the history
    var savedImageArr = JSON.parse(savedImageJson);
    
    // add current state as a new item to history
    savedImageArr.push(base64Image);
    
    // save the modified (added history)
    window.localStorage1.setItem("savedImage", JSON.stringify(savedImageArr));
    
    $("#numOfSavedHistory").html( savedImageArr.length );
  });
  
  // clear button just clears the localStorage (or any kind of API you use for persistent storage
  $("#clear").click(function() {
    //console.log("save");
      window.localStorage1.removeItem("savedImage");
    $("#numOfSavedHistory").html( 0 );
  });
  
  
  // undo last change (rollback to last state when you clicked save)
  $("#undo").click(function() {
    // clear canvas (to prevent white ink bug that also clears the background)
    canvas.width = canvas.width;
    
    //console.log("undo");
    
    // load/read saved states/histories
    var savedImageJson = window.localStorage1.getItem("savedImage");
    //console.log(savedImageJson);
    
    // if the history is undefined, create empty array
    if(savedImageJson == null || typeof savedImageJson == "undefined") savedImageJson = "[]";
    
    // parse the history
    var savedImageArr = JSON.parse(savedImageJson);
    
    // delete last item in history
    savedImageArr.pop();
    
    // save the modified (pop'ed history)
    window.localStorage1.setItem("savedImage", JSON.stringify(savedImageArr));
    
    // draw old picture on canvas
    var imageOld = new Image();
    imageOld.src = savedImageArr[savedImageArr.length-1];
    imageOld.onload = function() {
      contextCanvas.drawImage(imageOld, 0, 0);
    };
    
    $("#numOfSavedHistory").html( savedImageArr.length );
  });
  
  

  // set background
  var urlBackground = 'https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/400';
  var imageBackground = new Image();
  imageBackground.src = urlBackground;
  //imageBackground.crossorigin = "anonymous";
  imageBackground.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
  $("#target").drawpad();
  var canvas = $("#target canvas").get(0);
  var contextCanvas = canvas.getContext('2d');
  imageBackground.onload = function(){
    contextCanvas.drawImage(imageBackground, 0, 0);
    $("#clear").trigger("click"); // clear previous drawings when page refreshed
    $("#save").trigger("click"); // save the first image (background only)
  }
  
});
```

```css
body {background-color:rgb(248, 255, 227)}
        #target {
        width:500px;
        height:400px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cnbilgin.github.io/jquery-drawpad/jquery-drawpad.css" />
    
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cnbilgin.github.io/jquery-drawpad/jquery-drawpad.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <button id="undo">Undo</button>
        <button id="save">Save</button>
        <button id="clear">Clear Saved Picture</button>
    <span id="numOfSavedHistory">0</span>
        <div id="target" class="drawpad-dashed"></div>
        <div id="outputBase64"></div>

        </body>
        </html>
```