# Taking notes on a webpage on an iPad

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am currently working on my code and am wondering how can I create a box where an iPad user can take notes in the box with their finger/pen. I thought I saw it somewhere somwehre and tried to implement it but it doesnt work and cannot find the webpage I saw it from.

I am trying to google and using various help from different webpages. The expected result should be, that I can use my finger to draw on this webpage or a pen and take notes.

```js
let painting = false;

const canvas = document.getElementById('signatureCanvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function startPosition(e) {
  painting = true;
  draw(e);
}

function finishedPosition() {
  painting = false;
  ctx.beginPath();
}

function draw(e) {
  if (!painting) return;
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';

  // Adjust for touch events
  let clientX = e.clientX || e.touches[0].clientX;
  let clientY = e.clientY || e.touches[0].clientY;

  ctx.lineTo(clientX - canvas.offsetLeft, clientY - canvas.offsetTop);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(clientX - canvas.offsetLeft, clientY - canvas.offsetTop);
}

function clearCanvas() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', startPosition);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', finishedPosition);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);

// Touch event listeners
canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', startPosition);
canvas.addEventListener('touchend', finishedPosition);
canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', draw);
```

```css
.canvas-container {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row form-section centered-content" style="background-color:lavender;">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="canvas-container">
        <canvas id="signatureCanvas" width="300" height="150"></canvas>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mt-2" onclick="clearCanvas()">Notiz löschen</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you saying that your current code isn't working? It works fine in a browser, so I can only assume if that is the case that it's to do with the event handling you're using not being triggered by touch events

Comment: maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67155647/3706717 It's one of my old answer

Comment: I can confirm that this works as @RoryMcCrossan said, for me both with touch and pen on windows, as well as touch on android.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help but the code worked. I just didnt update my code it seems or maybe wrote something wrong in my code. As for now it also works in the designated way I choose. Thanks alot for the help!